# Slice Variable via another Variable Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have numpy code for a project and wanted to convert it to tensorflow.

I have a 2D Tensor like `x => [[0,1],[1,2],[2,3]]` etc. and I want to slice a 3D tensor `y` using this. e.g. `y[x[:,0], x[:,1], :]` but it doesn't work. Following is error:

`ValueError: Shape must be rank - but is rank - for 'strided_slice_?' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [-], [-], [-], [-].`

Can anyone please help!
Thanks

Comment: What's the shape and type of `y`?

Comment: its shape is `(600, 440, 5)`

Comment: this is exact error `ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 1 and 0
        From merging shape 1 with other shapes. for 'strided_slice_3/stack_1' (op: 'Pack') with input shapes: [?], [?], [].`
and shape of `x` is `(600, 440)`

Answer (score 0):

You need scalars to index into `y`, not tensors of rank 1+.

Try `y[x[0, 0], x[0, 1], :]` for a quick test.

Comment: but I need to access large chunk of `y` scalar access is not an option